# What is the quantum Fourier transform of $\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle$?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, quantum-fourier-transform

Given $|\psi\rangle = \alpha |0\rangle + \beta |1\rangle$ and $|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2 = 1$, what would the quantum Fourier transform of $|\psi\rangle$ be? I know it is of the form $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x |0\rangle + y |1\rangle)$, but how would I determine $x$ and $y$?

Is it possible that $QFT(|\psi\rangle) = |\psi\rangle$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quantum Fourier transform for a single-qubit case is just the Hadamard gate, so

$QFT |\psi\rangle = \alpha H|0\rangle + \beta H|1\rangle = \frac{\alpha+\beta}{\sqrt2}|0\rangle + \frac{\alpha-\beta}{\sqrt2}|1\rangle$

And $QFT(|\psi\rangle) = |\psi\rangle$ is possible if $|\psi\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $H$.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, though I'm not sure I understand why an eigenvector of H would remain unchanged when put through the QFT.

Comment: An eigenvector of a unitary operator remains unchanged by definition. I'm not sure if you want exactly the same vector or the same up to a global phase, in the first case you need the eigenvector that corresponds to eigenvalue of 1, in the second case either one will do.

Comment: Can you provide a source for that definition? I'm sorry, I'm pretty new to all of this and am not completely solid on a lot of the math. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I would recommend you to take a look at https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumKatas/#learning-path- - the first two tutorials in the learning path offer all definitions you need to get started with the math for quantum computing, including eigenvectors and eigenvalues. Alternatively, any source that defines an eigenvector will work :-)

Comment: @QuantumLearner: Concerning eigenvectors, if $|\psi\rangle$ is eigenvector of $H$ then $H|\psi\rangle = \lambda|\psi\rangle$, where $\lambda$ is respective eigenvalue. Since $H$ is unitary and hermitian, $\lambda = \pm 1$, hence $H|\psi\rangle = \pm |\psi\rangle$. Minus one is just global phase and can be neglected, i.e. $-|\psi\rangle = |\psi\rangle$.